# TextInput gets blank in case of large input value

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a simple React Native application for saving notes. I have a `TextInput` component which shows the pre-filled value, in case any, and you can change the input value. I have a state for controlling the input field, and have only `onChangeText` event attached. Here is my `Note` component:

```js
const NotePage = ({ note, handleGoBack }) => {
  const [noteText, setNoteText] = useState(note ? note.description : '');

  return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputStyle}
          value={noteText}
          multiline
          autoFocus={note === null}
          onChangeText={(text) => setNoteText(text)}
          textBreakStrategy="simple"
          placeholder="New Note"
        />
      </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

But, if I have a large text as the value for the `TextInput`, the value gets blank, not like there is no value, it seems like the text is getting transparent or something. And, when I press delete button on the keyboard, after deleting some character, it is visible again! Is is really weird.

Any help would be really appreciated! Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be a `ScrollView` bug (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22713).

A workaround can be to set the `maxLength` property so you can't type more than a certain amount of characters, the max amount before the `ScrollView` disappears:

```
// ...
<ScrollView>
  <TextInput
    value={noteText}
    multiline
    autoFocus={note === null}
    onChangeText={(text) => setNoteText(text)}
    textBreakStrategy="simple"
    placeholder="New Note"
    maxLength={1778}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

The amount of characters you can type before it disappears might differ on your end so play around with the value.

You could also set `editable` to `false` based on the maximum amount of characters:

```
editable={noteText.length <= 1778}
```

But replacing the `ScrollView` with a regular `View` might even work better if you're only rendering a `TextInput` as a multiline `TextInput` is itself scrollable.

Comment: ohk, there are quite a people facing this on ios also. `maxLength` would not be a solution after all it's a note taking app. And, replacing `ScrollView` with regular `View` works!! But while scrolling only the `TextInput` gets focused.. but i think for now it is a solid alternative. Thanks!